# A white blank screen comes up even though the page goes through

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

My goal is to control the user's data from the login page via the fakeAPI and pass it to the movies page, but after passing the user information, these errors appear before a blank page comes up.

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
// App.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import MovieList from './components/MovieList';

const App = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const handleLogin = async (username, password) => {
    // Simulate user authentication using the fake API
    const users = await fetchUsers();
    const matchedUser = users.find(
      (user) => user.username === username && user.password === password
    );

    if (matchedUser) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
      setUser(matchedUser);
    } else {
      alert('Invalid credentials. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setLoggedIn(false);
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
        <Routes>
          {/* Login page */}
          <Route path="/" element={loggedIn ? <Route to="/movies" /> : <Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />

          {/* MovieList page */}
          <Route path="/movies" element={loggedIn ? <MovieList user={user} onLogout={handleLogout} /> : <Route to="/movies" />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I dont understand what those mean.

Error image:
Cannot destructure property 'loggedIn' of 'user' as it is null.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loggedIn' of 'user' as it is null.
at MovieList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:414:5)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25955:22)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29241:17)
at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30537:20)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15547:18)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15591:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15648:35)
at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35522:11)
at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34769:16)
at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34692:9)

Comment: It sounds like the error is saying that the "element" that you're routing to can't be a `<Route>`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `<Router>`? Generally speaking that should never be directly rendered and rather instead you should either use `<>` as a wrapper or  `<BrowserRouter>` if you want to maintain state.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Because it forced me to use it otherwise i used navigate before

Comment: @BekirAkay you updated the error on this post. The error you added is for a component we cannot see, but I'll update my answer to include.

Comment: I don't see any code you've provided that is attempting to read any property, e.g. `loggedIn` from any `user` object/reference. Have you include ***all*** relevant code for your [mcve]? Share the `MovieList` component where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should structure your routes using the Routes and Route components:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import MovieList from './components/MovieList';

const App = () => {
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

const handleLogin = async (username, password) => {
    // Simulate user authentication using the fake API
    const users = await fetchUsers();
    const matchedUser = users.find(
    (user) => user.username === username && user.password === password
    );

    if (matchedUser) {
    setLoggedIn(true);
    setUser(matchedUser);
    } else {
    alert('Invalid credentials. Please try again.');
    }
};

const handleLogout = () => {
    setLoggedIn(false);
    setUser(null);
};

return (
    <Router>
    <Routes>
        {/* Login page */}
        <Route path="/" element={loggedIn ? <Navigate to="/movies" /> : <Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />

        {/* MovieList page */}
        <Route path="/movies" element={<MovieList user={user} onLogout={handleLogout} />} />
    </Routes>
    </Router>
);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to redirect a user if they're not logged in. This is possible, but your implementation is flawed. When you write `<Component />` the component is rendered when the containing function is called.

When you wrote `<Route path="/" element={loggedIn ? <Route to="/movies" /> : <Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />`

`<Route to="/movies" />` is rendered, hence the error you're receiving.

You should leverage the `<Navigate />` component, the documentation has a similar example to your code: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate

While this is a misuse of react-router, I've seen a lot of engineers thrown off because they did not understand the error. The real issue here is that you did not realize you were rendering the `Route` component as specified in the error.

This should work:
`<Route path="/" element={loggedIn ? <Navigate to="/movies" /> : <Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />`

#### Updated error

> Cannot destructure property 'loggedIn' of 'user' as it is null.
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loggedIn' of 'user' as it is
> null. at MovieList

This line is throwing the error: `<Route path="/movies" element={loggedIn ? <MovieList user={user} onLogout={handleLogout} /> : <Route to="/movies" />} />`

`loggedIn` is true but `user` is null. In general, it's important to know when a value is derived. `loggedIn` indicates whether there is a user, so derive its value from `user`.

```js
const loggedIn = useMemo(()=> !!user, [user]);
// i really prefer starting bools with "is" => isLoggedIn
```

Comment: My answer is to the initial post. I may update based on what was edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
```

and

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  setLoggedIn(false);
  setUser(null);
```

I just changed useState(false)'s to true and setUser(null) to false and take them back to old version of my code. And start the npm it worked.